# python for loop syntax error with len (I can't publish this question without the weird title)

Tags: python

`for(j in range(len(queries))):`

this line gives me a syntax error, what is wrong with it?
By the way, queries is a list variable

Comment: It should be `for j in range(len(queries)):`. Please see the [documentation for for-loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Mime and by the error you're getting, the syntax of your for loop is incorrect. The right one is

```
for j in range(len(queries)):
```

Using just one parameter in the `range()` function will make you iterate from `0` to the number you have put as parameter minus one, in this case the lenght of `queries` minus one. Using `range(0, len(queries))` achive the same.

You can also use `range(start, stop, step)` with three parameters:

- start    Optional. An integer number specifying at which position to start. Default is 0
- stop Required. An integer number specifying at
  which position to stop (not included).
- step Optional. An integer
  number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1

You can also use `j` as a variable inside the loop which will be something like `0,1,2,...,len(queries)-1`

More on `for` loop on the official [Python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)